# How to loop through object from API which is a random key value pair?(Angular)

Tags: angular

I have api response coming from server which is like

```
    {
      "name1":["value1","value2"],
      "name2":["value3","value4"],
      "name3":["value5","value6"],
       .......
}
```

I'm able to display the key here. But I want to know how to loop through the array which contains values.

.ts file

```
this.apiService.getDetails().subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    this.initialDataSource=new MatTableDataSource();
      this.initialDataSource=res;
      const transformedData = [];
      Object.keys(this.initialDataSource).forEach((data) => {
        transformedData.push({'key': data, 'value': `${this.initialDataSource[data]}`});
      })
      console.log(transformedData);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(transformedData);
      this.dataSource.paginator=this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort=this.sort;

  });
```

Currently it is taking entire values array as a single string so I'm not able to loop through it and display each item within value array.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: You cannot do it this way. If you have dynamics columns, you have to declare a array of string containing the columns ids. You can have a look on this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/angular/omaaqabvdad?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-dynamic-columns-example.html

Comment: I want to know how to display the values within array in angular

Comment: In a generic way: `<div *ngFor="let value of values">{{ value }}</div>`. Here is the official doc: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: Sorry I realised the problem in ts file...it is taking the entire value array as a single string. So I'm not able to loop through the values

Comment: In you ts file you are implicitly casting your data to string: ``${this.initialDataSource[data]}``. Remove the string interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many mistakes on your code.

You are affecting a `new MatTableDataSource` to your `initialDataSource` variable, and the line after, you are erasing this affectation by affecting `res` to `initialDataSource`.

On your loop, you are casting `this.initialDataSource[data]` to string using interpolation.

Here is what your code should be:

```
this.apiService.getDetails().subscribe((res) => {
      const transformedData = [];
      Object.keys(res).forEach((data) => {
            transformedData.push({ key: data, value: res[data] });
      })
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(transformedData);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
});
```

You can simplify you loop throug keys using a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map):

```
this.apiService.getDetails().subscribe((res) => {
      const transformedData = Object.keys(res).map((data) => ({ key: data, value: res[data] }));
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(transformedData);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
});
```